# Un pied dans la porte

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, régionalismes

Une question récente sur ce site faisait état d’un certain tour de langue nouveau et dans une certaine mesure controvesé qui aurait eu ***« un pied dans la porte »***. Interprétant le tout à la lumière d’une formulation qui dépréciait ce tour, et y appliquant une compréhension acquise en mon Québec natal, où l’expression est principalement utilisée pour désigner **la position de quelqu’un (ou quelque chose) sur le point de quitter ou d’être congédié**, j’en concluais que la tour controversé en question était déclaré comme étant sur le point d’être balancé à grands coups de pied dans le train dans le néant qu’il n’aurait jamais dû quitter, ce qui provoqua une réaction de ma part.

Bon ! Je me suis trompé en ce cas. On voulait plutôt dire qu’à l’instar d’un vendeur qui refuse de voir une porte claquée à son nez et qui y met le pied pour empêcher qu’on ne la fermât, le tour avait probablement acquis son droit de résidence en la langue française.

Recherchant la documentation disponible, j’ai trouvé ces exemples qui illustrent bien que mon opinion n’était pas fondé sur le néant :

> Parizeau était-il loyal envers ses disciples ? La réponse n’est pas évidente. Quand il annonce sa démission après le référendum d’octobre 1995, **même avec un pied dans la porte**, il éjecte le tout dévoué Jean Campeau du ministère des Finances. *<sub>—Source: La Presse +</sub>*

Dans le monde du sport, c’est une expression très commune, presque un lieu commun :

> Comme dirait mon collègue Benoît Brunet, on a l'impression que Julien est toujours à un but, une période, un match ou une défaite d'être congédié. On ne compte plus le nombre de fois où **il avait un pied dans la porte**. *<sub>—[Source](https://www.rds.ca/hockey/lnh/respect-pour-claude-julien-1.630729)</sub>*

Et au Québec, pour signifier l’intention de l’auteur de la question, on dirait le plus souvent ***« avoir / mettre un pied dans la place »***...

...mais on dit aussi, je dois le reconnaître suite à mes quelques recherches, ***avoir un pied dans la porte***.

Donc, je suppose que si on est dedans, avoir un pied dans la porte, c’est être sur le point de sortir, et que si on est dehors, c’est commencer à prendre pied à l’intérieur. Par ailleurs, ***mettre le pied dans la porte***, c’est travailler pour accroître sa présence à l’intérieur.

L’expression semble appartenir principalement au domaine familier. Il est assez difficile de trouver de la documentation à ce sujet : Robert, Larousse et le TLF sont discrets, le Glossaire du parler français au Canada de même.

- Est-ce un régionalisme propre au Québec, se doublant peut-être parfois d’un calque de l’anglais *« get one’s foot in the door »* pour son acception où, à l’instar d’un vendeur itinérant agressif, on empêche une porte de nous claquer au nez ?
- Dans un contexte ambigu, quelle interprétation serait à privilégier ?  L’une ou l’autre est-elle plus largement utilisée à l’écrit, hors le journalisme sportif québécois ? Suffisamment pour que certains s’y soient déjà penché ? Peut-être l’une ou l’autre aurait déjà été critiquée ?

Comment: https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~den%20Fuss%20in%20die%20Tuer%20kriegen%20%2F%20bekommen%3B%20den%20Fuss%20in%20der%20Tuer%20haben&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou

Comment: Un peu hors sujet, mais je vois un peu prés la même ambigüité avec l’expression « avoir le pied à/dans **l'étrier** » où, [quasi-]littéralement, on peut “[already] have a foot in the stirrup, ready to take off/leave” (= “one foot **out** the door”) ou figurativement (en français au moins), on peut  “[already] have a foot in the stirrup, [with his/her career potentially] ready to take off/succeed” (= “a foot **in** the door”).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De mon expérience personnelle, mais aussi de quelques références ([ici](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-dans-la-porte) ou [là](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/mettre+un+pied+dans+la+porte.html) par exemple), il semble que le sens le plus communément accepté soit le premier sens, c'est à dire être déjà un peu dans la place en visant plus. J'avoue que jusque là je n'avais jamais considéré que ca puisse vouloir dire autre chose, même si effectivement l'image fait du sens peu importe le...sens de celui qui passe par la porte :-)

Pour exprimer "sur le point d'être congédié", j'emploierais plutôt "Avoir déjà un pied dehors", si l'on veut rester sur une expression avec le mot "pied".

Si le contexte ne devait pas être clair, j'éviterais quoi qu'il en soit cette expression maintenant que j'ai conscience qu'elle peut être ambiguë...

Comment: Merci. Une réponse très raisonnable. Et pour éviter l'ambiguïté si elle devait *prendre pied dans le contexte*, privilégier, selon le type de transition invoquée, **«un pied dehors»** ou **«un pied dans la place»**.